# Looking for function to convert multipliers into addition

Tags: functions

Suppose we have the following: $m_1 m_2 m_3$

Where $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$ are constants $> 0$

I'm looking for a function $f$ such that:

$m_1 m_2 m_3 = 1.0 + f(m_1,m_2,m_3) + f(m_2,m_1,m_3) + f(m_3,m_1,m_2)$

and $f(1,x,y) = 0$
and $f(x,1,1) = x-1$
and $f(x,w,z) = f(x,z,w)$

I can't find case for $3$ constants $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$.  The case for $2$ constants I get following function:

$f(x,y) = [(x-1.0)+(xy-y)]/2$

we have
$1 + f(x,y) + f(y,x)$
$=1+ [(x-1.0)+(xy-y)+(y-1.0)+(yx-x)]/2$
$=2/2 + (2xy-2)/2$
$=xy$

also $f(1,y) = 0.0$
and $f(x,1) = x-1$

Is there a solution for $3$ variables? or general case of $n$ variables?

Answer (score 1):

The function $ f(x, y, z ) = \dfrac{xyz - 1}{3} $ seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you that works!   Would you know of another f such that if x>y then f(x,y) > f(y,x)

Comment: If $f(x,y,z)=(x y z-1)/3$  then $f(1,x,y)=(x y-1)/3$  and $f(x,1,1)=(x-1)/3$, but the Q says $f(1,x,y)=0$ and $f(x,1,1)=x-1.$

Comment: @user254665 when the q was asked the other requirements where not there.

Comment: @QthePlatypus.  That explains it. ...To the  OP: Please do not change a Q to a different one after accepting an answer . Ask a new Q separately.